# What does [::1] signify? when dialing with tcp

Tags: networking, tcp

```
Connection attempt failed: dial tcp [::1]:9109: getsockopt: connection refused

[ERR] CHNS: Connection attempt failed: dial tcp [::1]:9109: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I understand 9109 is the TCP port

Answer (score 2):

`[::1]` (technically, `::1`, but you put the brackets around it for a URI) is the IPv6 loopback address. You are trying to connect to a server in your own host via IPv6, but the connection is refused.

Comment: Where can I read about this notation? Also how did you know it was IPv6?

Comment: The _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_ documents the speical IPv6 addresses, and _[RFC 2732, Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URL's](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt)_ explains the brackets on the address. Simply search for `ipv6 addressing`, and you will get a lot of references.